# Got an error in the IBM Bluemix Weather Insights API used. Kindly help me out

Tags: ibm-cloud, weather, weather-api

I am referencing the documentation page here:
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/23/ibm-insights-weather-available-in-bluemix/

But I'm getting the following error :

```
{"metadata":{"version":"1","transaction_id":"1:677162605","status_code":404},"success":
false,"errors":[{"error":{"code":"AGW-0114","message":"Failed to parse apiname"}}]}
```

My Constructed URL is :

https://****:*****@twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v2/forecast/&format=JSON&geocode=11.9310,%2079.7852&language=en-US&units=e

Kindly help me with this issue .

Answer (score 2):

The constructed url needs to be like this:

https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v2/forecast/hourly/24hour?format=JSON&geocode=11.9310%2C79.7852&language=en-US&units=e

The differences are:

- call the REST API /forecast/hourly/24hour rather than just /forecast
- Add the ? at the end of the API so you pass the parameters
- Add the %2C in the geocode to represent the ,

See swagger doc [here](https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/#)